# How to update the amount when removing the product from the list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am on the checkout page and I am getting the total amount of products. I am using the `sum()` function to get the product amount and calculate the total amount.

I am getting the issue while removing the product. If I remove the product then I have to change the total amount. I am getting the price of the product in the remove function.

Would you help me out how to send the remove price to the sum() function to remove?

```js
$('.Selectedview').on('click', '.viewer', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').remove(); //Remove field html
  var removePrice=$(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find('.singleamt').val(); 
   alert(removePrice); // I am getting the remove product amount there

});


function sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".singleamt").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });

  var sumWithGST = sum + (sum * 0.18);

  return [sum, sumWithGST];
}
var totalamount = sum();
//alert(totalamount);
$('#subAmount').html(totalamount[0]);
$('#finalAmount').html(totalamount[1]);
//$("#sendamount").val(totalamount[2]);
```

```html
<div class="Selectedview">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading ">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[1]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[2]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[2]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>Total amount: $<strong id="subAmount"></strong></p>
<p>Final amount: $<strong id="finalAmount"></strong></p>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recalculate the sum. Please create a function where you call the sum() and update the HTML and call it after removing the product. look at the below code but i have not created a function. just move the redundant code into a function and it will work as expected.

```js
$('.Selectedview').on('click', '.viewer', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').remove(); //Remove field html
  var removePrice=$(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find('.singleamt').val(); 
   alert(removePrice); // I am getting the remove product amount there
   var totalamount = sum();

   $('#subAmount').html(totalamount[0]);
   $('#finalAmount').html(totalamount[1]);
});


function sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".singleamt").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });

  var sumWithGST = sum + (sum * 0.18);

  return [sum, sumWithGST];
}
var totalamount = sum();
//alert(totalamount);
$('#subAmount').html(totalamount[0]);
$('#finalAmount').html(totalamount[1]);
//$("#sendamount").val(totalamount[2]);
```

```html
<div class="Selectedview">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading ">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[1]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[2]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[2]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>Total amount: $<strong id="subAmount"></strong></p>
<p>Final amount: $<strong id="finalAmount"></strong></p>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, Your code is working, I need to know what code you removed?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to recompute the total with the function you used in the first place.

```js
$('.Selectedview').on('click', '.viewer', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').remove(); //Remove field html
  applyTotal();
});


function sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".singleamt").each(function() {
    sum += +this.value;
  });

  var sumWithGST = sum + (sum * 0.18);

  return [sum, sumWithGST];
}

function applyTotal(){
  var totalamount = sum();
  $('#subAmount').html(totalamount[0]);
  $('#finalAmount').html(totalamount[1]);
  //$("#sendamount").val(totalamount[2]);
}

$(document).ready(applyTotal);
```

```html
<div class="Selectedview">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading ">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[1]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
          <div class="sectionHeading">
            <h5>$1.00</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="timeslot">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[2]" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[2]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>Total amount: $<strong id="subAmount"></strong></p>
<p>Final amount: $<strong id="finalAmount"></strong></p>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, your answer is also working. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

you can create function to display the total and use that function whenever you want like this

```js
 $('.Selectedview').on('click', '.viewer', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').remove(); //Remove field html
            var removePrice = $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find('.singleamt').val();
            displayTotal();

        });


        function sum() {
            var sum = 0;
            $(".singleamt").each(function () {
                sum += +this.value;
            });

            var sumWithGST = sum + (sum * 0.18);

            return [sum, sumWithGST];
        }

        function displayTotal() {
            var totalamount = sum();
            $('#subAmount').html(totalamount[0]);
            $('#finalAmount').html(totalamount[1]);

        }

        displayTotal();
```

```html
<html>
<div class="Selectedview">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
                    <div class="sectionHeading ">
                        <h5>$1.00</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeslot">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[1]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
        </li>

        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-marginB">
                    <div class="sectionHeading">
                        <h5>$2.00</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeslot">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewer">Remove</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id[2]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="r_amt[2]" value="1.00" class="singleamt">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p>Total amount: $<strong id="subAmount"></strong></p>
<p>Final amount: $<strong id="finalAmount"></strong></p>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



</html>
```